# AWS Glue not picking up schema change

Tags: amazon-s3, schema, parquet, aws-glue

I was under the impression that AWS glue could pick up schema changes (say, I add a column) and automatically update the table. However, after submitting a test message with an extra column to my SQS queue, picked up by the lambda, processed, and then using Firehose to write a parquet file to S3, Glue has not changed the schema. I see the message in the table though, so I am confused why this did not add the column.

Are there any settings I should be aware of? I have already set the glue crawler to "update the table definition in the data catalog" when it detects schema changes in the data store.

Comment: Can you share the full Glue crawler configuration?